# Code-only answers override the purple deleted colour

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, deleted-answers, 10k-tools

In the [**N**ew **A**nswers **T**o **O**ld questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions) page on the 10k tools we can still see deleted answers. Whenever we have code-only answers that are deleted the normal purple/pink background is hidden by the code background.

In this image we can see that the code-only answer *looks like* it is not deleted.

[image: With Code Block]

However when the code block is removed, we can see that it is deleted.

[image: Without Code Block]

Comment: +1 for the hand drawn red circles, good job.

Comment: Of course, everyone is really looking at the "Punch" link.

Comment: @Tunaki I love that userscript! *punch*

Comment: What font was used for the ✓ and ✗ characters? If it is free source, I'd like to add it to a library.

Comment: @Jeeped The font is called *BR Hand Special™*. It is not open source and costs around 50 unicoins.

Comment: @BhargavRao I read 50 Unicorns. Priceless.

Comment: Thanks for reporting. Fix gonna be live with one of coming builds.

Comment: @Paweł Thanks a lot. (aside, lot of [bug]s and [feature-request]s wrt to the 10k tools are still waiting for recognition, hope your team will catch all of them too) All the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting, it should be fixed now.

Comment: to be clear: it's fixed in repo waiting for build, so should be live very soon.

Comment: Thanks @Pawe(l with dash) for that!

Answer (score 14):

The problem is that the `deleted-answer` class is only set on the inner div containing the post text, when it really (IMO) should be set on the enclosing table cell or whole row.

Here's a quick jQuery one-liner you can run in your browser console to fix it:

```js
$('table.default-view-post-table tr').has('.deleted-answer').addClass('deleted-answer')
```

Screenshots:

> Before:
> [image: screenshot]
>
> After:
> [image: after]

And yes, I'm planning on adding this into [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch).

Comment: Alternatively, something like `.deleted-answer {padding: 10px; margin: -10px}` might be faster and less error-prone.

Comment: Why so much jQuery?

Comment: @TinyGiant: Because SE uses it, that's why. :P And it saves typing.

Comment: But it's so... jQuery.

Comment: [There's never enough jQuery](http://www.doxdesk.com/updates/2009.html#u20091116-zalgo)

Comment: @Ilmari, [tag:status-completed]